# Running jest tests directly in Intellij Idea/WebStorm?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, reactjs, webstorm, jestjs

I'm using [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) to write tests in my ReactJS application. 
So far, to run my test suite, I need to type `'npm test'`.

Here's the snippet from package.npm:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/jest",
    (other stuff)
  },
  "jest": {
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/react"],
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "es6",
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "es6"
    ]
  },
```

Is it possible to run those tests within my IDE (IDEA/WebStorm) directly, preserving the configuration? I'm not a js guy, but for example WebStrom works perfectly fine with Karma. Shouldn't this be possible with jest-cli either?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make Jest test results shown in a tree view (like karma, etc.), a special integration is needed. WebStorm doesn't yet support Jest. Please vote for [WEB-14979](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14979) to be notified on any progress.

---

**EDIT: as of March 2017 the first version of Jest integration at WebStorm [has been released](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14979#comment=27-1968715).**

Comment: is there any way to debug this like you can for mocha tests by adding a node debugging config?

Comment: I don't care about tree view.  I just want to be able to run tests (especially on an individual basis), from IntelliJ, and seeing stack traces with links!

Comment: But the "auto-run" feature of a test suite with jest in webstorm is sooo slow to start. CLI is still the way to go...

Comment: I just setup Webstorm 2017.1.4 to natively use Jest for debugging. Click on the Configurations drop down, select Edit Configurations, click the green +, and then select Jest (you can setup special options here as well but default worked perfect for me).

Comment: I am trying to setup and none of your links helped me to configure IntelliJ

Comment: what problems setting it up have you faced? And what IDE version do you use?

Answer (score 14):

In WebStorm 9+ You can set this up as follows:

- Install Jest CLI: `npm install --save-dev jest-cli`
- Create node run configuration with javascript file set to `node_modules/.bin/jest`, and application parameter to `--runInBand`. `runInBand` tells `jest` to run in single process, otherwise there's a port conflict when running multiple node processes in debug mode
- Create some tests and run configuration in Debug mode (Ctrl-D/CMD-D). If you set breakpoints in your test or app code they should hit

It would be great though if you could click on `file:line numbers` in the output to go directly to the code.

[image]

Comment: thanks but I get  **SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word**     at transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/transform.js:320:12)

Comment: Make sure **not** to have a slash at the beginning of the path to the jest bin.

Comment: Actually it only crashing at JSX code now when debugging @sim

Comment: NOTE: IntelliJ currently cannot debug Jest with Node 8. Switch to Node 7 and it works fine:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27144
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7593

Answer (score 3):

app_sciences's answer is awesome, but does not work for Windows.

For windows, you can use next configuration:
[image: Windows webstorm jest configuration]

Provided configuration is taken from [here](https://liusy182.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/jest-how-do-you-debug-it/)

Comment: I just can't get webstorm to work with https://liusy182.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/jest-how-do-you-debug-it/

Answer (score 2):

For IDEA I'm using https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Run+Configurations for that purposes. For WebStorm it seems you can add your config by yourself https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html . The configuration you are talking about is on the software level. If you will configure to run it via your IDE it will definitely will run within the ENV variables and paths given, you just need to add the needed global paths and the commands to run.

Comment: I don't want to just add run configuration. I'd like my test's result to be visible within an IDE, so I could easily navigate to the one that fails, then to certain code line etc

Comment: just create npm script in your package.json (called test for example) and then select NPM run config in webstorm

Comment: what will that do to help debug? @KrzysztofKaczor