# Different behavior from Jest test when run locally and run via npm

Tags: javascript, css, jestjs, enzyme, test-framework

Pretty short question. I'm checking that the opacity of a checkbox is 0 at a particular point in my test. It works perfectly and passes when I run it locally in my IDE (Intellij).

`expect(getComputedStyle(checkbox.getDOMNode()).getPropertyValue('opacity')).toBe('0');`

However when I run my test via `npm t` it fails as it finds the opacity to be `''` and not `'0'` as expected.

I also tried

`expect(checkbox.getDOMNode()).toHaveStyle('opacity : 0');`

and got the same result (i.e. Passes locally and fails when run via npm).

I'm puzzled. Why the difference in test behavior between running locally and via npm ?

Comment: Depends on how exactly tests run in IDE. This isn't shown in the question. Both things run locally so *locally* may be not the right term.

Comment: Fair point. Is there anything that would work in all scenarios, no matter where it is run ?

Comment: Depends on your project. Since JSDOM behaves differently in, a reasonable explanation would be that test runs are performed with different Jest and `jsdom` package versions but I don't see how it's possible. Consider explaining how exactly you run tests in IDE and providing its config for tests. For starters, make sure your `test` script is `jest` with no args and make sure that IDE script calls `npm test` or `node_modules/.bin/jest` with no args, too. If there are args or environment variables set, that's the difference. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38385476 , not sure if Idea differs.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look. Much appreciated